# Constuctor can't get const char*

Tags: c++, pointers, char

Constructor

```
 CMyString::CMyString(const char* pString)  
 {
     int lenght = strlen(pString);
     cout << lenght;
 }
```

What i try to do

```
int main()
{
   const char* str = "test";
   CMyString test(str);
}
```

Error that i get

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CMyString::~CMyString(void)" (??1CMyString@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main MyString    C:\Users\art\source\repos\OOP\lab5\MyString\main.obj    1

what do i wrong?

thx

Comment: See the linked duplicate. The tl;dr version is that you declared that a destructor exists but never implemented it. Provide an implementation for `CMyString::~CMyString()`.

Comment: @cdhowie omg....thank you bro!!

Comment: No problem at all. Happy coding!